# Problem with indexed XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I scanned 2,8GB XML file for positions (Index) of particular tags. The I use `Seek` method to set a start point in that file. File is UTF-8 encoded. 
So indexing is like that:

```
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pathToFile)){
  long index = 0;
  while(!sr.EndOfStream){
    string line = sr.ReadLine();
    index += (line.Length + 2); //remeber of \r\n chars

    if(LineHasTag(line)){
      SaveIndex(index-line.Length); //need beginning of the line
    }
  }
}
```

So afterwards I have in another file indexed positions. But when I use seek it doesn't seem to be good, because the position is set somewhere before it should be. 
I have loaded some content of that file into char array and I manually checked the good index of a tag I need. It's the same as I indexed by code above. But still `Seek` method on `StreamReader.BaseStream` places the pointer earlier in the file. Quite strange.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,
ventus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seek deals in bytes - you're assuming there's one byte per character. In UTF-8, one character in the BMP can take up to three bytes.

My guess is that you've got non-ASCII characters in your file - those will take more than one byte.

I think there *may* also be a potential problem with the byte order mark, if there is one. I can't remember offhand whether `StreamReader` will swallow that automatically - which would put you 3 bytes to start with.

Comment: Well, that's true, there are non-ASCII characters in that file. Then how to index it correctly?

Comment: @Ventus: You could call `Encoding.GetByteCount(line)` and hope that it all keeps in sync. I can't immediately think of situations where it wouldn't.

Comment: It seems to be better now. I have to test it now. I can that still sometimes it's not perfect, but I hope it's going to be OK.